# Cronjob with docopt

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron, docopt

I have a really simple code with docopt which creates a directory. The program works perfectly like this:

```
dbb create_dir
```

I need to run this using crontab in ubuntu 12.04. I used `crontab -e` and added this line:

```
0 14 * * * dbb create_dir
```

which should run the code on 2pm every day. My problem is this doesn't work. I checked

```
0 14 * * * mkdir test_dir
```

and it worked. So I thought the problem is not with the cron and as I could run the code without cron, I guess the main problem is the combiniation of these two. Is there any way to fix this? Thanx

Comment: Is dbb on your path? What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I used python setup.py develop and it added dbb to bin. So I can run it from anywhere. By "doesn't work" I mean it doesn't create the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my friend figured it out. When I type "echo $PATH", I get this:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

I added "echo $PATH" to the crontab and the result was:

```
/usr/bin:/bin
```

So the paths are not the same. So I had to use

```
/usr/local/bin/dbb create_dir
```

instead of `dbb create_dir`